# JQ Not Taking In Variable Data

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am unsuccessfully trying to add variable data to a json within a ci script.  I am attempting to use the `--arg VariableName VariableData` notation.

For example purposes, I am only passing $date which has already been set earlier in the script.  In the outputted JSON, the literal string $date is outputted instead of the variable.

```
jq --arg date "$date" '.sections[0].builds += [{"title": "Version MyVersion", "timestamp": "$date", "iOS": "My_URL.plist" }]' builds.json > builds1.json
```

**This results in:**

```
{
  "title": "MY Title",
  "columnCount": 1,
  "notes_OFF": "First_Test",
  "sections": [
    {
      "title": "My Title",
      "builds": [
        {
          "title": "Version MyVersion",
          "timestamp": "$date",
          "iOS": "My_URL.plist"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Original JSON:**

```
{
  "title": "MY Title",
  "columnCount": 1,
  "notes_OFF": "First_Test",
  "sections": [
    {
      "title": "My Title",
      "builds": [
        
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `"$date"` with `$date` in your filter.

Comment: Thank you. What about for mixing a literal string and variable? For instance something like `--arg version $version .... "title": "Version $version", ...`

Comment: For string arguments use `--arg version "$version"` and handle it as a string, i.e. `{title: ("Version " + $version)}` or `{title: "Version \($version)"}`.
For JSON arguments (including numbers for instance) use `--argjson version "$version"` and handle it as any JSON object, i.e. in case of a number `{ver: ($version + 3)}`.

Comment: Thank you.  So concatenation in JQ needs to be inside parentheses?

Comment: No, the value of a field has to be inside parentheses if it is more complex than a simple value. Neither `{key: $value}` nor `.key = "another " + $value` needs parentheses.